# How to extract GeoJSON/WKT from drawn layer in Leaflet?

Tags: leaflet, geojson

I would like to extract coordinates in GeoJSON/WKT format from user drawn polygon. I found next code:

```
drawnItems = new L.FeatureGroup();
drawnItems.addLayer(layer);
myjson = drawnItems.toGeoJSON();
console.log(myjson)
```

But in console I see only `Object {__ob__: Observer}` like [this](https://img.ctrlv.in/img/16/09/28/57ebd08e2aece.png)

I used example from [here](https://bl.ocks.org/danswick/d30c44b081be31aea483)

What I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you were expecting to get a string, then you just missed the `JSON.stringify(myjson)` on the next line of the example you refer to.